# need starting point on an ORDER BY

Tags: php, join, mysqli

The website contains images. These images can be ranked. When an image is ranked, the value can be 1,2, or 3. To save ranking I have a table `ranking_items`. The images are displayed as thumbnails. The boss would like me to order them by rank. the problem is, how do I also include images in the result with no entry in the `ranking_items`?

```
$db->query("SELECT file_name 
    FROM images, ranking_items 
      WHERE images.id=ranking_items.image_id 
       ORDER BY ranking_items.rank ASC");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `FROM table1, table2` you are doing a `JOIN`.

Try to `LEFT JOIN` the ranking_items table.  This will return all rows, and put NULLS in the places where the join fails.

```
SELECT file_name 
FROM images
LEFT JOIN ranking_items ON images.id=ranking_items.image_id 
ORDER BY ranking_items.rank ASC
```

Comment: this worked, thank you.  is it safe to say that right join would not include the nulls?

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN` is the opposite of `LEFT JOIN`.  Meaning the NULLs would be where rows do not exist in the `images` table, compared to `LEFT JOIN` which adds NULLs when the row doesn't exist in the `ranking_items` table.  For more info see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-full-join-in-mys

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT file_name 
FROM images LEFT JOIN ranking_items 
ON images.id=ranking_items.image_id 
ORDER BY ranking_items.rank ASC
```